# How to pass a callback method to another class in C#

Tags: c#, dll, callback, delegates

I'm using C# and I have an App A and a DLL B I've created.
I'd like to be able to do the following:

1. In App A, create my callback method:

   ```
   public void MyAppMethod(string inComing){
       Debug.WriteLine("callback returned: " + inComing);
   }
   ```
2. In App A, set the CallBack method in B, like `B.SetCallback(MyAppMethod);`
3. In DLL B, use the callback to return a string:

   ```
   private void SomeMethod(){
       //do some stuff
       MyAppMethod("hello");
   }
   ```

How can I set this up?

Comment: How is this different than using events or delegates?

Comment: I don't know that it is - that's why i'm asking for help on how to set this up...

Comment: It is not different than delegates or events. You can use Action delegate.

Comment: That's a bit too broad to go into here. I would just read up on c# events as a starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Events:

App A:

```
public void MyAppMethod(string inComing){
    Debug.WriteLine("callback returned: " + inComing);
}

B.MyAppMethod += MyAppMethod;
```

App B:

```
public event Action<string> MyAppMethod;
private void SomeMethod(){
    //do some stuff
    if(MyAppMethod!=null) MyAppMethod("hello");
}
```

Using delegates:

App A:

```
public void MyAppMethod(string inComing){
    Debug.WriteLine("callback returned: " + inComing);
}

B.MyAppMethod = MyAppMethod;
```

App B:

```
public Action<string> MyAppMethod;
private void SomeMethod(){
    //do some stuff
    if(MyAppMethod!=null) MyAppMethod("hello");
}
```

These codes will work as are. However, there are many important things you must consider before using this code, which you will find [on the web](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)

Comment: I accepted your answer, but used slightly different code (see below). Also, your Delegate answer is (almost)exactly the same as your Events answer, so I think it should be edited.

Comment: @wayneh. thanks. BTW, the event and delegate codes are slightly different. notice their declarations (first line of App B) and their consumptions (last line of App A)

Comment: Technically speaking, event is a special case of delegate, for which operation = is invalid. That basically means that you can change keyword event to delegate and every code should work exactly the same way. Of course, concept of using delegate is different from event, but it's about the way you structure programs. That is why the examples look pretty the same.

Comment: @wayneh I see your point here. I tried to avoid overcomplicating the solution with unnecessary `delegate` keyword since `Action<>` is sufficient in 99% of cases. note that, **events are not delegates. that's a common misconception** even though their syntax is very similar to each other

Comment: @wayneh it's more a matter of aesthetics and taste whether to use `Action` and `Func` or to write your own delegate. but in some cases having named delegates increases readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using.

APP A:

```
public void MyCallBack(string status)
{
   // Add callback text to the status window
   StatTxt.AppendText(status);
}

// Set the callback method in DLL B
B.HollaBack = MyCallBack;
```

DLL B:

```
public delegate void CallBackDelegate(string status);  
public CallBackDelegate HollaBack
{
   get; set;
}

private void DoCallBack(string inMsg)
{
   // Make sure the callback method was set
   if (HollaBack != null)
   {
      // send text to the callback method
      HollaBack(inMsg);
   }
}

// Invoke the callback anywhere within DLL B
DoCallBack("show this in the status window");
```